# UWP - How to implement a data entry form in "MasterDetailsView" template?

Tags: uwp, master-detail, windows-template-studio

I have a nice working MasterDetails view made with the Windows Templating Studio, and I want to use the "Noselection" state to implement a data entry form.

But... I've absolutely no idea wher to strat for that...

(I know how to force displaying of NoSelection display, setting "Selected" value to null.)

Any help would be nice!

[EDIT 1]

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NoSelectionContentTemplate">
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <views:AddContrat />
            <!--TextBlock
                x:Uid="Contrats_NoSelection"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
                TextAlignment="Center" /-->
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But...  has an error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail
>   Description Error XDG0062 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table:
>   Residences'.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc,
>   sqlite3 db)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch
>   timer)+MoveNext()    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch
>   timer)+MoveNext()    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.N  GestionGarages  ContratsPage.xaml   38      System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table:
>   Residences'.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc,
>   sqlite3 db)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch
>   timer)+MoveNext()    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch
>   timer)+MoveNext()    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReade

The code compiles and run with no problem...

What could be the cause of this error ?

Comment: `MasterDetailsView` has  [`NoSelectionContentTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.masterdetailsview.noselectioncontenttemplate?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable)property, you could place the data entry here.

Comment: Thank you @NicoZhu-MSFT for your answer, replaced the TextBlock in NoSelectionContentTemplate (edited the post), and it works!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP - How to implement a data entry form in “MasterDetailsView” template?

MasterDetailsView has [`NoSelectionContentTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.masterdetailsview.noselectioncontenttemplate?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) property, you could place the data entry here like the following.

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Mail" 
                                    RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform 
                                  ScaleX="2" 
                                  ScaleY="2"/>
                            </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                        </SymbolIcon>
                        <TextBlock Text="Please select item" 
                                   FontSize="24" 
                                   Margin="0,12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
</controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
```